# Is there a point in overriding while only calling the 'super' implementation?

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is a curiousity question about the world of Java programming.

Let's say I have this in my code

```
public interface IDoSomethingAndSomethingElse {

    int doSomething();

    int doSomethingElse();

}


public abstract class AbstractDoSomethingAndSomethingElse implements IDoSomethingAndSomethingElse{

    public int doSomething() {
        return arcaneAndMysticalProceedings();
    }

    public abstract int doSomethingElse(); //thanks PM77-1
}

public class MyDoSomethingAndSomethingElse extends AbstractDoSomethingAndSomethingElse{

    @Override
    public int doSomething(){
        return super.doSomething();
    }

    public int doSomethingElse(){
        return mystiriousIncantation();
    }

}
```

My question is this: Is there a point in the concrete implementation to override doSomething() like this? Any use for it? Can you think of a use case for that to be useful?

**EDIT**: To make my question a bit more precise; Is there situations in which it would make a difference if I had not ovveriden `doSomething` exactly like I did above (without actually adding anything to it)?

Comment: Just a side note: Your abstract class does not fully implement the interface.

Comment: @PM77-1 As far as being compilable it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no functional difference.

The only difference I can think of is that without overriding it, the method is not "declared" on that class, only on the superclass. For example:

```
class A {
    void doSomething() {
    }

    static class B extends A {
        @Override
        void doSomething() {
           super.doSomething();
        }
    }

    static class C extends A {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Method m : B.class.getDeclaredMethods())
            System.out.println(m.getName());
        for(Method m : C.class.getDeclaredMethods())
            System.out.println(m.getName());
    }
}
```

In that example, `doSomething` is only listed for `B.class`.

Comment: So is there a use case in which that would make a difference significant enough for me to have to choose between the two?

Comment: I can't think of a practical one.

Comment: No, there isn't. Any code (which would have to be reflection code, like the `main` method example in the answer), which depends on a method being defined in a particular class in an inheritance hierarchy, is buggy.